# mysql FUNCTION GROUPING does not exist

Tags: sql, function, mariadb, rollup, mariadb-10.2

When using `WITH ROLLUP` I receive this error:

> **#1305** - FUNCTION GROUPING does not exist

My DB version:

```
innodb_version  5.7.28
version     10.2.30-MariaDB
```

Strange that  `WITH ROLLUP` works, but not `GROUPING()`. I would like to replace the nulls

Any idea?

My SQL:

```
SELECT
IF(GROUPING(`Categorie`), 'All Categorie',`Categorie`) AS `Categorie`,
`Grootboek`,
SUM(`Bedrag2020`) AS `Bedrag2020` 
FROM `vw_resultaat_ytd` 
Group by
`Categorie`,
`Grootboek` WITH ROLLUP;
```

As described in:
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-rollup/

Comment: Please show us your query and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: GROUPING is not implemented in MariaDB. [SELECT WITH ROLLUP](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select-with-rollup/).

Comment: @FritsNagtegaal, add query in your original question please

Comment: MariaDB 10.2, MariaDB 10.3, and MariaDB 10.4  is a  replacements for MySQL 5.7   the grouping() function is related  to mysql 8.0.12 .. this mean that in your mariadb version the grouping function is not available

Comment: thanks @scaisEdge and Akina this explains

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, `grouping()` is not supported.  Unless `Categorie` can be `NULL`, then just use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Categorie, 'All Categorie') AS Categorie, 
       Grootboek, SUM(Bedrag2020) AS Bedrag2020
FROM vw_resultaat_ytd 
GROUP BY Categorie, Grootboek WITH ROLLUP;
```

If `Categorie` can be `NULL`, then you need to replace the value with an invalid value and undo that:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Categorie IS NULL THEN 'All Categorie'
             WHEN Categorie <> '<NULL>' THEN Categorie
        END)  AS Categorie, 
       Grootboek, SUM(Bedrag2020) AS Bedrag2020
FROM vw_resultaat_ytd 
GROUP BY COALESCE(Categorie, '<NULL>'), Grootboek WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Great Gordon, that help me out. Finally this was the end solution I was looking for, but I did not fully explain it:

```
SELECT  Categorie, 
COALESCE(Grootboek, concat('All ', Categorie)) AS Grootboek,
SUM(Bedrag2020) AS Bedrag2020
FROM vw_resultaat_ytd 
GROUP BY Categorie, Grootboek WITH ROLLUP;
```